# How can I start tmux in a readonly environment?

Tags: raspberry-pi, tmux, raspbian, readonly

I'm trying to start a tmux session in a readonly environment, but receive the error:

```
pi@raspberry(ro):~/development$ tmux
error creating /tmp//tmux-1000 (Permission denied)
```

This raspberry pi project may lose power unexpectedly, and a UPS is not an option. In order to avoid SD card corruption, the system was made readonly following the instructions in [this](https://medium.com/swlh/make-your-raspberry-pi-file-system-read-only-raspbian-buster-c558694de79) post (distilled below for context). I'd still like to use `tmux` for various reasons as development continues on this project.

*How can I continue to utilize `tmux` in this context?*

Given that `rw` and `ro` are aliased to command to switch between read/write and readonly, would this necessitate changing something in those aliases?

---

#### Summary of readonly process

1. Edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and add `fastboot noswap ro`
2. Replace logging `sudo apt-get install -y busybox-syslogd && sudo apt-get remove -y --purge rsyslog`
3. Update the file `/etc/fstab` and add the `,ro` flag to all block devices.
4. Also add the entries for the temporary file system at the end of the file:

```
tmpfs        /tmp            tmpfs   nosuid,nodev         0       0
tmpfs        /var/log        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev         0       0
tmpfs        /var/tmp        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev         0       0
```

5. Move files

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dhcp /var/lib/dhcpcd5 /var/spool /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo ln -s /tmp /var/lib/dhcp
$ sudo ln -s /tmp /var/lib/dhcpcd5
$ sudo ln -s /tmp /var/spool
$ sudo touch /tmp/dhcpcd.resolv.conf
$ sudo ln -s /tmp/dhcpcd.resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

6. Edit `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-random-seed.service`:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStartPre=/bin/echo "" >/tmp/random-seed
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-random-seed load
ExecStop=/lib/systemd/systemd-random-seed save
TimeoutSec=30s
```

7. Append `/etc/bash.bashrc/:

```
set_bash_prompt() {
    fs_mode=$(mount | sed -n -e "s/^\/dev\/.* on \/ .*(\(r[w|o]\).*/\1/p")
    PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h${fs_mode:+($fs_mode)}\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
}
alias ro='sudo mount -o remount,ro / ; sudo mount -o remount,ro /boot'
alias rw='sudo mount -o remount,rw / ; sudo mount -o remount,rw /boot'
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_bash_prompt
```

8. Append `/etc/bash.bash_logout`:

```
mount -o remount,ro /
mount -o remount,ro /boot
```

---

---

#### Edit to add:

Tried adding `mode=01777` to `/tmp` in `/etc/fstab/`, but still get the same error.

```
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ cat /etc/fstab 
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=ea7e04d2-01  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro          0       2
PARTUUID=ea7e04d2-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,ro  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
tmpfs           /tmp          tmpfs   nosuid,nodev,mode=01777            0       0
tmpfs           /var/log      tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
tmpfs           /var/tmp      tmpfs   nosuid,nodev            0       0
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ tmux
error creating /tmp//tmux-1000 (Permission denied)
```

The same thing happens in `rw` mode.

---

#### Edit to add #2:

Troubleshooting:

```
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ tmux
error creating /tmp//tmux-1000 (Permission denied)
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ ls -ld /tmp/
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 260 Oct  5 21:17 /tmp/
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ sudo chmod 01777 /tmp
sudo chmod 01777 /tmp
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ tmux    ###### IT WORKED!
[exited]
pi@raspberry(ro):~$
```

Success after the `sudo chmod`

---

#### Edit to add #3:

The `tmp.mount` file does include the `01777` mode.

```
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ cat /run/systemd/generator/tmp.mount 
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
Before=local-fs.target

[Mount]
Where=/tmp
What=tmpfs
Type=tmpfs
Options=nosuid,nodev,mode=01777
```

#### Edit to add #4:

`/tmp` is not a symlink, there do not appear to be errors in the mounting...

```
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 260 Oct  5 01:44 /tmp
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ sudo systemctl status tmp.mount
* tmp.mount - /tmp
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
   Active: active (mounted) since Sun 2020-10-04 21:59:28 EDT; 1min 46s ago
    Where: /tmp
     What: tmpfs
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tmp.mount

Oct 04 21:59:27 raspberry systemd[1]: Mounting /tmp...
Oct 04 21:59:28 raspberry systemd[1]: Mounted /tmp.
pi@raspberry(ro):~$ logread |grep tmp
Oct  4 22:01:14 raspberry authpriv.notice sudo:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status tmp.mount
```

Answer (score 3):

The `tmpfs` entry in `/etc/fstab` does not specify any particular mode for the directory `/tmp`, so it is created with `0700`. Change the entry to

```
tmpfs     /tmp        tmpfs   nosuid,nodev,mode=01777
```

to allow all users to create files in `/tmp`.

Comment: I tried, but get the same error. I will update the question with results...

Comment: What does `ls -ld /tmp` show as permissions? It should be `drwxrwxrwt`. If it isn't try manually changing it as root with `chmod 01777 /tmp`.

Comment: `ls -ld /tmp/` returns 
`drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 260 Oct  5 21:17 /tmp/` ... the chmod worked. Why wouldn't the mode be taking at startup? (It looks like it's taking 744 instead of 777... (??))

Comment: I know I've seen the preceding bits before, but are the `01` needed for mode? Could that be the issue?

Comment: I don't see why it seems to be ignoring the `mode=`. The `01` adds the sticky bit (`t`) to the directory for security (see `man chmod` section *RESTRICTED DELETION...*). If you are using systemd, the fstab entry should normally be converted to a Unit file in `/run/systemd/generator/`. Check that Unit file preserves the mode in `Options=`.

Comment: It is *not* preserving the mode! (Updating the question; the `/run/systemd/generator/tmp.mount` file shows 644!)

Comment: You need to look inside the file `/run/systemd/generator/tmp.mount`. You should see a line beginning `Options=` followed by the `nosuid,nodev,mode=01777` copied from the fstab entry.

Comment: Oops. Yes, the mode is copied inside of that file (updating question).

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Perhaps `/tmp` is a symbolic link? Try `ls -ld /tmp` without a slash at the end. Also, does `sudo systemctl status tmp.mount` show the unit is active and had no errors.

Comment: Doesn't appear `/tmp` is symbolic. No errors during the `status` check. `logread` shows nothing about `tmp` when checking. I will say, interestingly: the date/time is off. The commands displayed in the question were run on 07Oct2020, not 04Oct202. Not sure if that's a clue or not.... (updated question with output)